# Cannot copy database to remote host. Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, database

I have local MySql database, when I try to copy it to new empty db on remote host I got error:

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

How can I copy whole database, without changing the encoding? Why it works locally and not remotely?

right side is localhost
[image: right side is localhost]

Answer (score 0):

Could be you have some column involved  in index  that have a long char definition  ..eg `varchar(255)` in you table destination .. you could tru to reduce this dimensione when not needed in your new tables creation   eg

from

```
col1 varchar(255),
col2 varchar(255),
```

to

```
col1 varchar(16),
col2 varchar(32),
```

(remember that some char coding reauire more then a char for single values)

Comment: my destination is empty there is nothing,  table destination not exists. It is empty fresh database

Comment: then create the destination table with reduced  dimension for involved  columns..

Comment: This is a big database I can not just change it individually for each one

Comment: my is a suggestion ..  and for what i know in this case there are not much alternatives ..   check for original date format and eval the possible reason of this behavior  now that you know the problem... in your schema you have not the width ...  of the columns

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for this error might be that the local database used the utf8 character set (up to 3 bytes per character) while the remote database uses utf8mb4 charset which can use up to 4 byts per character.

Since index lengths (e.g. unique indexes or primary keys on varchar colums) are defined with character lenths but are stored internally using their byte-representation, you have a lower maximum length for unique varchar or text columns.

To solve this issue, you can also set the default character set of the remote database to utf8 instead of utf8mb4.

Comment: but I use only utf8. I added screen , can you look what should I change there?

Comment: As you can see on your screenshot, locally, use use latin1 as a character set while remote, you are using utf8. Latin1 is a one-byte encoding (i.e. each character occupies exactly one byte). Change the characters sets to be exactly the same and you should be able to move your database.